# How to insert variables into a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm working on a simple multiplication app for coursework. It has a slider to select a number between 1 and 20. The idea is to create a 'times table' that lists the first 50 items from whatever number is selected from the slider. The error message I'm getting is 'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'multiplier'.
Thanks for your help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject) {
        println(sliderValue)
    }
    var multiplier = 1
    var cellContent = ["\(multiplier) times 1 is 1", "1 times 2 is 2", "1 times 3 is 3"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellContent.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking time to answer my question. The suggestions didn't help me. Here is my tutor's method:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject) {
        table.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let timesTable = Int(sliderValue.value * 20)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(timesTable * (indexPath.row + 1))
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Set cellContent inside of viewDidLoad()

Comment: @Arbitur would that really make a difference?

Comment: I dont have my mac infront of me but just move it inside a function and try if you still get thje error. I dont think you can set variables using other variabels outside a function.

Comment: @Arbitur what do you think that would do?

Answer (score 1):

Make `cellContent` as:

```
var cellContent: [String]!
```

Then initialize it on `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cellContent = ["\(multiplier) times 1 is 1", "1 times 2 is 2", "1 times 3 is 3"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TODO

1. you have to fix your array ;) only the first element is dynamic and uses multiplier. the rest are static strings
2. you have to save the slider value and reload the table on sliderMoved
3. AND you need to format the string before giving it to the cell
4. you need to fix your array again so the result of 'X * Y = Z' (you hardcoded Z)

in your case formatting could be a simple *replacing* the string

```
...

@IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject) {
    multiplier = sliderValue.value; //TODO find right property to save
    myTable.reloadData() //reload the table
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    
    //format it before setting it to the table
    //TODO find right method to help you here
    var str = cellContent[indexPath.row]
    str.stringByReplacingOccurancesOf("(multipler)", NSString("%d", multiple))
    str.stringByReplacingOccurancesOf("(result)", NSString("%d", multiple*indexPath.row+1))

    cell.textLabel?.text = str
    return cell
}

let cellContent = ["(multiplier) times 1 is (result)", "(multiplier) times (result) is 2", "(multiplier) times 3 is (result)"]

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var multiplier = 1
    var cellContent = ["\(multiplier) times 1 is 1", "1 times 2 is 2", "1 times 3 is 3"]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject) {
        println(sliderValue)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellContent.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```